# Повторное подключение к mysql

Tags: mysql

Использую функцию для подключения к БД

```
<?php
function my_querry($my_query)
{
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$baza);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'cp1251');
if ($conn->connect_error) die ($conn->connect_error);
$query = "$my_query";
$result =$conn->query($query);
if (!$result)die($conn->error);
mysql_close($conn);
return $result;
}

?>
```

При первом вызове функции отрабатывает на ура
А при втором какой-то косяк

Comment: Какой косяк, опишите подробно

Comment: Я понял в чем причина require_once 'login.php';

Comment: require 'login.php'

Comment: Просто после вызова функции обьект подключени не уничтожается и нового соединения с базой данных не происходит так как require_onсe не дает

Comment: А как правильно удалить обьект подключения к базе данных